# how to reset all stored data store using shared preferences

Tags: android

I have created an activity where i have used shared preferences for storing data..now in another activity i have an reset button..when i click on the reset button the data store will be lost..so how that can be done..my code is

code in activity1:

```
    public void writeToRegister()
    {

            // Write history data to register
            SharedPreferences preferences1  = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1  = preferences1.edit();
            editor1.putInt("iHistcount", CycleManager.getSingletonObject().iHistCount);
            for(int i=0;i< CycleManager.getSingletonObject().iHistCount;i++)
            {
                editor1.putLong("dtHistoryDate"+Integer.toString(i), CycleManager.getSingletonObject().dtHistory[i].getTime());

            }
            editor1.commit();
    }

    public void readFromRegister()
    {
            // Read history data from register
            SharedPreferences preferences1 = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            CycleManager.getSingletonObject().iHistCount=preferences1.getInt("iHistcount", 0);
            for(int i=0;i< CycleManager.getSingletonObject().iHistCount;i++)
            {
                Long x=preferences1.getLong("dtHistoryDate"+Integer.toString(i), 0L);
                CycleManager.getSingletonObject().dtHistory[i]=new Date(x);
            }
    }
```

code for Activity 2:

```
Button pBtnReset = new Button(this); 
    pBtnNextMonth.setOnClickListener(pBtnReset OnClickListener);
    Button.OnClickListener pBtnReset OnClickListenernew Button.OnClickListener()
    {
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {


                }
    };
```

so what i have to write in second activity reset button so that it clear the stored data

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Get your `Editor` and call `clear()` something like this:
**Edit**: as the user DDoSAttack mentioned.
There are two ways of getting `SharedPreferences`

1: getting default `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
```

2: getting specific `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = Context.getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and here is how you'll clear it.

```
public void clear()
{
     SharedPreferences prefs; // here you get your prefrences by either of two methods
     Editor editor = prefs.edit();
     editor.clear();
     editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: @AdilSoomro What is variable con `getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);`? Is it Context?

Comment: @StackOverflowError yes it is [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wipe all the data in a preference file call `clear()` from the `SharedPreferences.Editor` instance

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()

Comment: Also, I don't think your code works as it is written. You need to specify a filename for the SharedPreferences class. So it should look like: SharedPreferences preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 4):

its very easy..

```
yourEditor.remove(" thing you want to remove on start");
```

and then give must

```
yourEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SharedPreferences.Editor clear()` method.

See [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear())

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
```