# GooglePlay update App and wipe data

Tags: android, google-play, sharedpreferences

I need to update an application on Google-Play but **I WANT** that all the old settings saved via *Shared Preferences* and *Local Storage* will be wipe instead of being kept (because I have change the main structure of the data that will be saved and it's not compatible anymore with the old one).

How can I do that programmatically?
Thank you in advance for the future answers.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694562/how-to-reset-all-stored-data-store-using-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I would do it:

If you haven't already, create an Application class that extends android.app.Application. Make sure you declare this in your manifest. Read more about this here - http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android.

Then in your applications onCreate method, check the version of the app, and if it matches the new version, run your methods to clear out the shared preferences,local storage.
You can then set a boolean preference that the 'upgrade' has been completed,so your app doesn't try to clear out the data every time it's run.